# OAuth2 Authorization Code - Outlook rest API

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, office365api, outlook-restapi

I would like to download the emails and their attachments from my Outlook account via Python. Therefore, I have used the [official python script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial) with some changes since I didn't want to employ Django. Here below you can see my two unsuccessful attempts, the two corresponding errors and some comments. If I am not mistaken the issue arises when I try to obtain the Authorization code for getting the access token. During this step I can't make my app sign in successfully and automatically. Although I only  present in this post the issue with the Authorization code, I would like to make you aware that a second issue comes from the incorrect access token I obtain using my client_id, client_secret and my manually obtained Authorization code.

Note that I am using the so called "Azure AD v2 authentication endpoint" (as suggested in both https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial) in order to register and authenticate my app. It is worth stressing that I have also tried to employ the Azure AD and OAuth (i.e. the second approach to handle app registration and user authorization 'https://manage.windowsazure.com/') without any success. What is the correct approach in my case? Where is my mistake? Given my problems I believe I am registering my app wrongly.

Thanking you in advance, I wish you all a nice day.

**Modified script**:

```
# Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE.txt in the project root for license information.
#from urllib.parse import quote, urlencode
from urlparse import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode
import requests
import base64
import json
import time
import httplib

# Client ID and secret
client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx' 
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

# Constant strings for OAuth2 flow
# The OAuth authority
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'

# The authorize URL that initiates the OAuth2 client credential flow for admin consent
authorize_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?{0}')

# The token issuing endpoint
token_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token')

# The scopes required by the app
scopes = [ 'openid',
           'User.Read',
           'Mail.Read',
           'offline_access']

def get_signin_url(redirect_uri):
  # Build the query parameters for the signin url
  params = { 'client_id': client_id,
             'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
         'response_mode': 'query',
             'response_type': 'code',
             'scope': ' '.join(str(i) for i in scopes)
           }

  signin_url = authorize_url.format(urlencode(params))

  return signin_url

signin_url = get_signin_url("http://localhost/myapp/")

## first attempt
signin_url_r = signin_url.replace('https://', "")
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(signin_url_r)
#conn.request("GET", "code")
#conn.request("GET","/")
#r1 = conn.getresponse()
#print(r1.read())
#print(r1.status, r1.reason)

## second attempt
resq = requests.get(signin_url)
print resq.status_code
print resq.text
print resq.url

#with open('authhelper_f_v0.html', 'w') as outfile:
#   outfile.write(resq.text)
```

**Errors**:

(1)

```
ERROR ---> conn.request("GET", "code")
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

(2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
etc..
```

**Comments**:

The first attempt gives the error (1) that I believe comes from the lack of the word "code" in the get response. If I print the "resq.text" from the second attempt, I can indeed see that the get response is not the one expected (i.e. GET  HTTP/1.1 302 Found Location: http://localhost/myapp/?code= xxxxx&session_state=xxxx&state=xxx 
-- see "Redirect request after successful sign in" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started)  but rather the one you can see in (2), that is the Sign in Outlook 
page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you experiencing authentication issues?

If so, You can check your authentication question by looking at the link below:

[Authorize access to Azure Active Directory web applications using the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)
[Looking at the Different OAuth2 Flows Supported in AzureAD for Office 365 APIs](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/looking-at-the-different-oauth2-flows-supported-in-azuread-for-office-365-apis)

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna read it once again. To answer your question, Yes, I can't make my script sign in successfully and automatically.